# How to uncheck checkbox of Use Config Settings in Catalog Product Inventory

Tags: product, cataloginventory

I want to uncheck checkbox **Use Config Settings** by default in Inventory section in **Catalog=>Product** section as below image---

[image]

I know that we can update it from DB query but I want to make them uncheck when adding new products.

Comment: Why would you want that? That would only be useful when you have a different value for a specific store/storeview. If you uncheck them and save the product, all values will be saved separately.

Comment: yes, that I want. I will send my custom value into them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the checkbox state is hardcoded in the template.

So you need to remove all occurrences of the `checked="checked"` in the template

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml`